# Mac/Cocoa: Embed a terminal window in my app

Tags: cocoa, macos, terminal

Anyone found out if it's possible to "embed" an instance of Terminal into an app? It would be awesome if it also just inherited the tab functionality and drag-drop-ness as well. I saw a couple similar questions on here that mentioned [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) but it seems like there should be an easier way. Like a NSTerminal object I can pop into a view.

I asked the Panic guys about this. They have a terminal window in Coda that for all intents and purposes looks/functions exactly like Terminal.app running standalone on the desktop. However, their response was that they had to write that themselves from scratch. I'm hoping someone has figured out a better way!

Thanks!

Comment: Was there anything you've ended up with?

Comment: I don't know how to embed terminal window by itself but there is a way to execute terminal commands - Process+Pipe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the [Pathfinder SDK from Cocoatech](http://www.cocoatech.com/sdk).

Comment: The link is a 404 now, was the SDK discontinued?

Comment: Anybody has a backup of the SDK? I am very interested in that topic.

Comment: The SDK lives here: http://support.cocoatech.com/kb/features-and-development/can-i-contribute-to-path-finders-development

Answer (score 0):

No such thing AFAIK. I don't think embedding a full-featured terminal into an unrelated app is a common enough need that anybody would have made a control like that — even Panic only use it in the one app.