# Is it possible to embed a terminal window within a cocoa xib/nib?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, terminal

I looked at another questions (which i could only find one) which asked something similar more than few years ago, but none of the links mentioned seem to be relevant or work anymore.

- [Mac/Cocoa: Embed a terminal window in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673195/mac-cocoa-embed-a-terminal-window-in-my-app)

I am wondering if it's possible without going to extremes to embed a terminal window displaying a tool such as top (an interactive command-line tool) in a tty output embedded within the gui of a cocoa app (os x). I tried some things with `NSTask`, but clearly that isn't the way to go.

I'm really looking for a starting place to go off... or if this type of thing is even within reason. thanks

Comment: I'd say that was non-trivial.  It's one thing to create a pipe to a command line tool, feeding stdin and capturing stdout/stderr and it's another thing to emulate the terminal window (i.e. VT220-like escape codes etc.).  You might be better off starting *Terminal.app* from within your Cocoa app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NMSSH](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH) lib and example they gave [here](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH/tree/master/Examples/PTYExample). Basically they made interactive terminal view controller, so you can use it for your needs.

Comment: Looked at it and found it's an implementation with 300 LOC. So for sure it's not what the user wants. It's exactly what trojanfoe mentioned in the other comment as a total different beast to write a terminal emulator